# WP MultiSite API - Create new sites

Tags: multisite, rest-api

I'm building an app for iOS/Windows. I want to allow my users to register / create a new sub site on my domain via the app. How can I achieve this? Does the REST API allow this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in the core or in the rest API for this requirement.
You can try this plugin, https://github.com/remkade/multisite-json-api

Sorry, but I see no other chance and no more to say in this answer.

The core function to create a new site in the network of the installation is [`wpmu_create_blog`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/). But there is no access from the REST API.